# Frontend is empty wordpress

Tags: plugins

While installing the wordpress site with zip files code and database i have loaded admin but frontend is empty and showing following errors. with empty home page.

Please find the screenshot
http://prntscr.com/fp2ycu

Please find the code on `functions.php` on 872 line:

`function get_blog_id_assign_to_js() {
    $site_info = get_site();
      if(isset($site_info)) {
         $blog_Id = $site_info->blog_id;
      }
}`

Thanks

Comment: I suspect that there are missing files in the WordPress installation because the function `get_site()` is part of the core WP installation. Try recopying the the core files to your server.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is due to the 'purple-event' theme.

```
on functions.php line 872
```

Comment: I can help you send the code on functions.php on line 872

Comment: You need to write the code here

Comment: function get_blog_id_assign_to_js() { $site_info = get_site(); if(isset($site_info)) { $blog_Id = $site_info->blog_id; }

Comment: which code i have to write here

Comment: Try running a different theme to figure out why

Comment: another theme is running properly

Comment: 'get_blog_id_assign_to_js()'  where is this function being used?

Comment: add_action('wp_head','get_blog_id_assign_to_js');
function get_blog_id_assign_to_js() {
    $site_info = get_site();
    if(isset($site_info)) {
        $blog_Id = $site_info->blog_id;
    }
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var blog_id = "<?php echo $blog_Id; ?>";
</script>

<?php }

Comment: The code is like above

Answer (score 0):

try checking for the function `get_site()` it will check if the function exists

replace

```
function get_blog_id_assign_to_js() {
$site_info = get_site();
  if(isset($site_info)) {
     $blog_Id = $site_info->blog_id;
  }
}
```

with this code

```
function get_blog_id_assign_to_js() {
    if(function_exists('get_sites')){
        $site_info = get_site();
        if(isset($site_info)) {
        $blog_Id = $site_info->blog_id;
        }
     }
}
```

Comment: iam getting following errors:screenshot:http://prntscr.com/fp3xg8

Comment: I have commented the code in wp-config.php   /* Multisite */
/*define( 'WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE', true );
define('MULTISITE', true);
define('SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', false);
define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', '10.0.0.70');
define('PATH_CURRENT_SITE', '/entervent/entervent-live/');
define('SITE_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
define('BLOG_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);*/